# Seeking verification: $\sqrt[\large 3]{a \cdot \sqrt a} = \sqrt a\quad?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$\sqrt[\large 3]{a \cdot \sqrt{a}}=?$

Is the answer simply $\sqrt{a}\quad?$

Comment: $\displaystyle \sqrt[3]{a \sqrt{a}}=\sqrt{a}$

Comment: The answer is $\sqrt{a}$ only if $a=\sqrt{3}$

Comment: In general, $\sqrt[3]{a \cdot \sqrt{a}}$ has six values, whereas $\sqrt{a}$ has only two.

Comment: @WillO: $\sqrt a$ denotes the _principal_ square root of $a$ (and is only well-defined for non-negative real numbers). Similarly, $\sqrt[3] a$ is only well-defined for real numbers. So $\sqrt[\large 3]{a \cdot \sqrt a} = \sqrt a$ for all $a$ for which the left-hand side is defined.

Comment: The answer is correct if $a>0$.  As pointed out, for $a<0$ you need to take into account complex numbers, and perhaps you get different values (or perhaps not).

Comment: @GEdgar: But if $a < 0$, then $\sqrt a$ is undefined. That is not to say that the equation $z^2=a$ has no solutions in $\mathbb C$; but that is not what $\sqrt a$ means.

Comment: @TonyK:  So you are saying that it would be incorrect to express the roots of the general quadratic $ax^2+bx+c$ as $(-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac})/2a$ ?

Comment: @WillO: That's a good question! If $a$ is a complex number, then $\sqrt a$ is not unambiguously defined $-$ but the solutions of the equation $x^2 = a$ can be unambiguously written as $\pm \sqrt a$ because the solution set is the same whichever square root we take. So I would say that $\pm \sqrt a$ is a benign misuse of notation.

Answer (score 4):

$$\sqrt[3]{a\sqrt{a}}=\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{a^2}\sqrt{a}}=\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{a^3}}=\sqrt[6]{a^3}=\sqrt{a}$$

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is correct: $\sqrt[3]{a \cdot \sqrt{a}}=(a \cdot a^{1/2})^{1/3}=a^{1/3}\cdot a^{1/6}=a^{1/3+1/6}$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your answer is correct. Simply write $a\sqrt{a}=\sqrt{a}\times\sqrt{a}\times\sqrt{a}$.

Answer (score 2):

$\sqrt[\large 3]{a \cdot \sqrt a} = \sqrt[\large 3]{a \cdot a^{\frac{1}{2}}} = \sqrt[\large 3]{a^{\frac{3}{2}}}= \left ({a^{\frac{3}{2}}}  \right )^{\frac{1}{3}}=a^{\frac{1}{2}}= \sqrt{a}$.